# How to get files names inside folder using regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to retrieve  all files names inside a specific folder, but I need to use regular expression in which I need to get files names depends on a number in the file name. For example :

> fitness-0Chromosom1

I mean zero in this case, I wrote the following:

```
//GetFiles on DirectoryInfo returns a FileInfo object.

                var pdfFiles = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Rounds/Fitness/AUV" + 1).GetFiles("fitness-"+geneticIteration+"*"+".txt");
```

Where `geneticIteration` is the number represent 0. Is it true or not?

Comment: You're using a wildcard search here, not regular expressions.

Comment: Is `fitness-0Chromosom1` the name of the folder or the file? Your code makes it seem like it's a file name.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but it seems like a bit of linq would do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code above will return all file names matching "fitness-**[a number]***.txt" in directory "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/Rounds/Fitness/AUV1".

Example results could be (given that "a number" = 0):

- fitness-0Chromosom1.txt
- fitness-0abc.txt
- fitness-0.txt

Answer (score 0):

GetFiles(path) also accepts the another parameter called 'searchPattern' where you can pass your regular expression. Another way to match the file name with your regular expression is using the Regex.IsMatch(path, pattern), which will return the true or false based on the comparison/match.

Comment: Search pattern is a wildcard pattern and not a regular expression